# joining two string in a single RDD to form new RDD in pyspark

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark, bigdata, rdd

I have an rdd & after apply `collection`, it is like below;

```
rdd = [('Amazon', '2016/01/09', '17:06:24', '17:10:03'),('Amazon', '2016/02/09', '17:06:55', '17:10:00'),('Amazon', '2016/02/09', '17:10:02', '17:19:00'),('Amazon', '2016/02/09', '17:13:09', '17:19:00'),('Aliexpress', '2016/03/09', '17:00:40', '17:23:00'),('Aliexpress', '2016/03/09', '17:03:50', '17:12:05'),('Aliexpress', '2016/03/09', '17:10:12', '17:12:38'),('Aliexpress', '2016/03/09', '17:13:23', '17:23:00')]
```

but I want to transformed the rdd in such a way that after apply `collection` I want to see the output like below;

```
Newrdd = [('Amazon 01','17:06:24', '17:10:03'),('Amazon 02','17:06:55', '17:10:00'),('Amazon 02','17:10:02', '17:19:00'),('Amazon 02','17:13:09', '17:19:00'),('Aliexpress 09', '17:00:40', '17:23:00'),('Aliexpress 03', '17:03:50', '17:12:05'),('Aliexpress 03','17:10:12', '17:12:38'),('Aliexpress 03', '17:13:23', '17:23:00')]
```

I want to join for example `Amazon` with `01` ( `01` is the month, comes from '2016/01/09').

I did like this;

```
Newrdd = rdd.map(lambda y: y[0].join((y[1].split('/')[1])))
print(Newrdd.collect())
```

But I am not getting the desired output collection. Anyone could tell me why?

Comment: Are you getting rid of the full date, too?

Comment: @ Alexander Cécile.. No I want to keep the months. In any case I solved like this; Newrdd = rdd.map(lambda y: (y[0]+' '+y[1].split('/')[1], y[2], y[3])). thanks Alexander.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve like below;

```
Newrdd = rdd.map(lambda y: (y[0]+' '+y[1].split('/')[1], y[2], y[3]))
```